# Add changelog file to classpath in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, maven, classpath

In my spring boot project, I have an endpoint that read the content of my `CHANGELOG.md` file.
I would like to read my CHANGELOG file from class path because I have something like this in my code :

```java
ClassPathResource myChangeLogFile = new ClassPathResource("CHANGELOG.MD");
```

Answer (score 0):

You must include it in the generated JAR file or put it in a directory that is included in the classpath by default (like src/main/resources).

For the inclusion in the JAR file you can do it as follows:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${build-helper-maven-plugin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-artifacts</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifacts>
                    <artifact>
                        <file>CHANGELOG.md</file>
                        <type>md</type>
                        <classifier>changelog</classifier>
                    </artifact>
                </artifacts>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```